# Null field in select dropdown

Tags: django, django-models

How do I get rid of the Null choice in a select dropdown? For example, I have the following model --

```
class Network(models.Model):
    type = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices = [('closed','closed'),('open','open')])
```

When I use the form in the template, I get three choices in the dropdown:

```
-------
Closed
Open
```

How do I get rid of this Null choice? So the select dropdown will only have the `Closed` and `Open` options?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField.empty_label) ([via](http://suwala.eu/blog/2010/11/05/remove-empty-choice-choice-field-django)):

> By default the  widget used by ModelChoiceField will have an
>   empty choice at the top of the list. You can change the text of this
>   label (which is "---------" by default) with the empty_label
>   attribute, or you can disable the empty label entirely by setting
>   empty_label to None

Answer (score 2):

Set `blank=False` in your model.

From the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#choices):

> Unless `blank=False` is set on the field along with a `default` then a label containing `"---------"` will be rendered with the select box. To override this behavior, add a tuple to `choices` containing `None`; e.g. `(None, 'Your String For Display')`. Alternatively, you can use an empty string instead of `None` where this makes sense - such as on a `CharField`.

Answer (score 0):

```
choices = [("","-- Select an option --"),('closed','closed'),('open','open')]
```

Comment: Your answer can be improved by providing more insight on the solution you are proposing.